# How to stop Speech Recognition Engine listening its own speech

Tags: c#

I have written a speech recognition engine in C# using

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer;
        SpeechSynthesizer sre = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        int count = 1;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        try
        {
            var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(culture);
            _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            _recognizer.LoadGrammar(GetGrammer());
            _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechRecognized);

            _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

            sre.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male, VoiceAge.Child);
            sre.Rate = -2;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }

    private static Grammar GetGrammer()
    {

        var choices = new Choices();
        //add custom commands
        choices.Add(File.ReadAllLines(@"Commands.txt"));
        //to add the letters to the dictionary
        choices.Add(Enum.GetNames(typeof(Keys)).ToArray());

        var grammer = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(choices));

        return grammer;
    }

    void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {

        string speech = e.Result.Text; 

    //to type letters in open application like notepad
   if (Enum.GetNames(typeof(Keys)).Contains(speech))
    {
        try
        {   //send the string to the application
            SendKeys.SendWait("{" + speech + "}");
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {

        }            
    }  

    //handle custom commands
        switch (speech)
        {
             case "day":
                sre.Speak("Friday");
                break;
        }
    }       
}
// where speech receives the text which the user speaks and also present in the loaded grammar (text file)
```

My code produces a speech recognition engine where if a user asks "day" it replies "Friday" which in turn has a "day" in it. So it goes on a loop and keeps on replying "Friday". What is the best way to stop the engine listening while it is speaking.

**Note**: I know the grammar can be changed to a convincing way like "What day it is" but I need it as "day" itself.

Also I am not providing reproducible code as this issue might be I am missing something basic. And I have tried using `bool bAbleToListen=true;` as suggested in some StackOverflow question. But, was unable to find it useful

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `RecognizeMode.Multiple` to `RecognizeAsync` method.

> **Multiple**
>       Member of System.Speech.Recognition.RecognizeMode
>
> **Summary:**
>  Specifies that recognition does not terminate after
>   completion.

So maybe you want it to terminate and start all over again after `Speak`?

```
_recognizer.SpeechRecognized += (sender, args) =>
{
    sre.Speak("trololo");
    _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Single);
};

_recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Single);
```

Answer (score 1):

`if(sre.State == "Speaking"){ /* don't listen */}`

Simply don't run the listening code if the speech synthesizer is speaking.

Comment: And remember to enable listining again once it's done speaking.