# Do not act on synthesized response

Tags: python-2.7, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I am trying to make an offline voice controlled home assistant. I use `pocketsphinx` for speech to text and `espeak` for text to speech, like if i give a command "open browser", then it opens the browser and speaks back "open browser processed".

The problem is when I connect to an external speaker, pocketsphinx recognises the "open browser processed" and this goes into a loop.

How can I configure pocketsphinx to pause for a little more time before recognising the next word?

I am using the livespeech function and code with Python.

Comment: Simply do not start recognition while TTS playing. Related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625265/android-speech-recognition-conflicting-with-text-to-speech http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816491/how-to-stop-speech-recognition-engine-listening-its-own-speech http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400840/stopping-speech-recognition-before-using-text-to-speech

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev  Can the livespeech function be configured, such that after recognising a word, it stops for 3 seconds then again starts recognising?

Comment: You can simply use blocking tts inside speech loop, it does not start recognition until you inside the for loop.